# React native navigation 5 passing updated component

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am new to react native and its navigation modules. I have a simple `dashboard.js` file where I am using `tab navigator` like this -

```
 <Tabs.Navigator tabBarOptions={{ activeTintColor: '#ff5757' }}>
    <Tabs.Screen
       options={{
       tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => 
        <Icon name='star-border' size={30} padding={15} color={color} />,}}
        name={'Orders'}
        component={Order}
        initialParams={{user}}
   />
<Tabs.Screen
component= {AnotherComponent}
/>
```

As you can see I am passing `InitialParams` where I have `user` props. And I can easily get it in `Order` component by `route.params`.

However, in my `dashboard` component I also have a method that runs every `1 minute` and updates `user` props.

I can't get the updated value of `user` props in `Order` component. I am stuck with this for 2 days. In the past I have done like this -

```
<Tabs.Screen
component = {() => <SomeComponent props= {props}/>}
```

And it worked fine. But with `react-navigation 5` its not working any more.

Please help me if anyone knows. plz.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks like I can pass component like this after all `<Tabs.Screen component = {() => <a props = {props} />. But I also need to have access to navigation as well. :(

Comment: Using above way giving error like `Looks like you're passing an inline function for 'component' prop for the screen`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial props seems to be a constant also as per the documentation you have to use redux or context api to update the badge counts in the tabs so I think it will be better to take that approach to handle this problem. Came up with a count changing scenario just like yours using context API.

```
const CountContext = React.createContext(0);

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View>
      <CountContext.Consumer>
        {value => <Text>Home! {value}</Text>}
      </CountContext.Consumer>
    </View>
  );
}

const MyTabs = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <CountContext.Provider value={count}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>{count}</Text>
        <Button title="count" onPress={() => setCount(count + 1)} />
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ title: 'My home' }} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Settings"  component={SettingsScreen} options={{ title: 'My home 2' }} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </View>
    </CountContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

This way you can skip the navigation params and directly send data to the tab, and this data can be read from other tabs or somewhere down the tree as well.

You can check the full snack here
https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/5c2b97

Comment: thanks a lot mate. this is why people who servers on stackoverflow will go to heaven.