# Cannot update props passed via react navigation

Tags: react-native

I have a container where the API calls happen. I need to pass the response I get to another component which is not the child of the above container. I can't pass in props like how you usually do since it is not a child component of the above container. What I do is, I pass the response to the above container's child component and from there I use :

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate('Whatever',{
  reason: this.state.reason
});
```

To pass in the reason as prop to the "Whatever" component. Now, the problem is this "reason" prop does not get updated when it changes in the container from where it is being passed.

Now, I am aware that since we are not passing props like how they are usually passed that's why we won't be able to get the updated props in whatever component. I am aware that I might have to change the structure of my app as well, but I cannot afford that right now.

Is there any way via which I can update the reason prop in the whatever component?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will have to use context, check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61920816/1435722

Answer (score 0):

You can use params in react navigation

--updating params https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#updating-params

--passing params https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#passing-params-to-a-previous-screen

--passing params to nested component https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#passing-params-to-nested-navigators