# React native (Expo) refresh previous screen after pressing button in header React navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I am in this difficult situation where I need some help.

I am developing this app that displays the local events or activities.

GPS distance filter screen:

[image: Text]

MainTabNavigator with screens including TopTabNavigator:

[image: Text]

I have this navigation structure:

MainTabNavigator ->

- Tab 1: 'Events'

  - Stack navigator

    - TopTabNavigator

      - Tab 1: 'Popular'

        - FlatList
      - Tab 2: 'This week'

        - FlatList
      - Tab 3: 'Soon'

        - FlatList
      - Tab 4: 'Online events'

        - FlatList
    - Gps Distance Filter screen
- Tab 2: 'Activities'

  - TopTabNavigator

    - Tab 1: 'Popular'

      - FlatList
    - Tab 2: 'All'

      - FlatList

        - Tab 3: 
          etc...

The MainTabNavigator has a header provided in the options property:

```js
<Stack.Screen
    options={{
        headerTitle: '',
        headerLeft: () => MainTabNavigatorLeftHeader(navigation),
        headerRight: () => MainTabNavigatorHeaderRight(navigation),
        headerStyle: MainHeaderStyle
    }}
    name="Events"
    component={EventsScreen}
/>
```

Which has a button in the header and clicking on it will open the GPS distance filter screen where a radius can be selected to view content within a certain KM radius.

Then when you press on the back button on the Gps Distance Filter screen included in his header, you come back to the maintabnavigator with the top tabs and the flatlists inside it. So when the KM radius has been changed (i save the selected radius via AsyncStorage) i need to refresh all flatlist's from all Top tab screens.

I have tried to do this via the focus addlistener or hook, but then all lists will be refreshed also on a top tab change or top tab swipe, is there any way to do this efficiently?

The Toptab screens are all generated by one component, so I only need to trigger one function in the component to refresh all screens.

Comment: This might help, its on using context to update parent https://stackoverflow.com/a/61920816/1435722

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan I am trying to use the context API, when I check if the context value has changed in the focus event i get 'false' and when i click on a button in the same screen i get value 'true' (which is expected) how could it be different?

Comment: Its really hard to say without looking at the code :(